# Why does my current location marker change from a person to an arrow?

Tags: android, osmdroid

I'm using the code provided by the wiki https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library-(Kotlin)

To test I'm using an emulated android device and my physical phone.
The issue I am having is that my current location marker seems to change depending on which device I'm using.

On the emulated device, my current location mark shows up as the black arrow. This is what I would prefer it to be. On my physical device however, it shows up as the person icon. To make things more convoluted the emulated device once showed the marker as a person for a moment before changing all by itself to the arrow.

What is delegating the default my location marker icon? I know I can always manually change it to whatever. But I'm concerned that there is some sort of state the application is in that changes the marker.